# Send multiple files for download to a user on click of a button in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, click, download

How to send multiple files for download to a user/browser on click of a button ?

I know how to sent single file for download. How to send two or more files ?

Comment: how do you do that for a single file ?

Comment: use return type of Action method as FileResult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search points at the [following link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1724314.aspx/1).

Ultimately, HTML is designed for single request / response communication. Your options are to consider multipart documents, or perhaps zip your output files together.

EDIT: There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616580/multiple-files-download-in-asp-net) as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224784/how-to-download-multiple-files-using-asp-and-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Some seconds late, but I think Nick is right. You could find some source code to zip all your files and send them as one :)