# Export GRIDVIEW to Excel to multiple excel files

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel, radgridview

I have gridview(Telerik RadGrid) that gets generated on fly based on the data returned from a SP. I need to export its data to excel inside a loop. Currently I have

`CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)FindControl("eqtypes");
                for (int i = 0; i < cbl.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (cbl.Items[i].Selected)
                    {
                        Getdata(arg, -1);
                        GridView1.Rebind();
                        GridView1.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
                        GridView1.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
                        GridView1.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
                        GridView1.ExportSettings.FileName = cbl.Items[i].Value;
                        GridView1.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
                    }
                }`

```
Getdata(arg, -1); // is the methood that pulls the correct data based on the item selected in the checkboxlist.
```

Everything works great except when I export I only get the last selected item data with only one exerted file. I need to export one file for each item selected. looks like its a postback problem. What would be the  workaround?

Comment: What type is GridView1? The standard asp.net grid view control doesn't seem to have methods such as "Rebind"

Comment: its is a radgrid, telerik radgrid.

Comment: Im not familiar with those controls. If i were to hazard a guess, could it be a problem with the "ExportToExcel" function overwriting previous files, so you only end up with one file containing data from the latest selected item?

Comment: i dont know, the files are named different on each iteration. The problem is the postback, in order to export files a full postback is required but in the foreach loop there is no postback until it reaches to the end and do the postback & export only last one.

Comment: Oh i see. Ignore my previous comment, i was way off. I'm not sure if there is a way to send multiple files to the client per request. You may have to either write some logic to create each excel file and then zip it up in a folder and send that to the client. Or have a separate postback for each file dowload.

Comment: See this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422243/send-multiple-files-for-download-to-a-user-on-click-of-a-button-in-asp-net-mvc